# MacBook Pro internal screen issue

Tags: screen

my son tripped and dropped his MacBook Pro. One corner of the screen is now black - looks like a crack on the inside. Apple told me it would most likely be about $500 to fix. Are there any other solutions?  It works fine, just the screen.

Comment: You said it works fine? so how bad is the screen damaged, is it still functioning, just have a small area not working. Is it worth $500 to replace it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Model:

You could do it your self to save some.

If you ONLY replace the LCD part and not the whole display the costs are in the range of $100 to $200 depending on which LCD type you choose.

There are some very good instructions how to at [ifixit web site](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_13%22).